# Neural Network from scratch issue with backprop function

Tags: python, math, deep-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm implementing a NN from scratch to better understand how they work but I have ran into an issue.

For background, the network has two hidden layers. The input layer has 784 neurons, the first layer has 16 neurons, the second has 13 neurons and the output layer has 10 neurons. (I'm using the MNIST dataset.)

This is the code for the backprop:

```
def backward_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, Z3, A3, w1, w2, w3, X, Y):
    m = Y.size

    dZ3 = A3 - desired_output_vector(Y)
    dw3 = 1 / m * dZ3.dot(A2.T)
    db3 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ3)

    dZ2 = w3.T.dot(dZ3) * ReLU_d(Z2)
    dw2 = 1 / m * dZ2.dot(A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2)
    
    dZ1 = w2.T.dot(dZ2) * ReLU_d(Z1)
    dw1 = 1 / m * dZ1.dot(X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1)
    
    return dw1, db1, dw2, db2, dw3, db3
```

The math is based on this video by Samson Zhang: https://youtu.be/w8yWXqWQYmU. In his video, he only has one hidden layer. So what I've done is extend the concept to two hidden layers. I am using the same labeling convention in my network; that is Z for unactivated and A for activated. Also note that the first hidden layer is 1, so on...

The network decreases in accuracy when I run it, what is wrong with the code? Is the math correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @max  Sorry, I have just edited the question.

Comment: There is a method, 'gradient checking', that can be very effective at finding bugs in implementations of backprop. See the excellent answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506521/what-exactly-is-gradient-checking for more info, or Andrew Ng's lecture at https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/htA0l/gradient-checking

Comment: You have two questions here. First question: is your math calculation correct? Second question: is your python implementation faithful to the math formula you've calculated? Here you've only showed us your python implementation, so we can answer neither the first nor the second question.

Comment: Note that if you have a function `f`, you can compute an approximation of its partial derivative with respect to a variable `x` as `(f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2*h)`, for some small value `h` such as `h = 1e-5`. This computation is less efficient than actually implementing the math formula of the gradient of `f`, so you don't want to use it when running the gradient descent. But it's good practice to implement both the exact math formula and the approximation formula, so that you can compare them and test for mistakes in the math formula this way.